# Error al querer pasar el codigo python a Java

Tags: java

Estado practicando con java pero anteriormente habia hecho practicas con python y esas mismas practicas las estoy haciendo pero ahora en Java. no se si estoy haciendo bien la sintaxis en Java tomando como referencia a python. El programa hecho en python funciona de la siguiente manera: el programe me pide que ingrese el nombre del producto y el precio de este, luego me pide si quiero agregar otra compra, si digo "SI" procede a realizar el mismo procedimiento anterior y cuando digo que "NO" el programa me muestra por pantalla todas las compras realizadas con sus respectivos precios y descuentos.

**CÓDIGO PYTHON**

```
def regist(a,b,c):
        registro.append(a)
        registro.append(b)
        registro.append(c)
    def mostrar():
        x=0
        for i in registro:
            x+=1
            if x%3==0:
                print("{}".format(i).ljust(25," "))
                print("")
            else:
                print("{}".format(i).ljust(25," "),end="")
    
    i=1
    registro=["Producto","Precio","Descuento"]
    while True:
        producto=input("Ingrese el nombre del {}°.producto: ".format(i)).title()
        precio=float(input("Ingrese el precio del producto: "))
        if precio>500:
            descuento="20%"
            precio*=0.80
        else:
            descuento="5%"
            precio*=0.95
        regist(producto,round(precio,2),descuento)
        de=input("Desea agregar otra compra[SI/NO]: ").upper()
        if de=="NO":
            break
        i+=1
        print("")
    print("")
    mostrar()
```

****CÓDIGO JAVA****

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Ejercicio8{
      static ArrayList<String> registro=new ArrayList<String>();
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner entry=new Scanner(System.in);
    
        int i=1;
        registro.add("Producto");
        registro.add("Precio");
        registro.add("Descuento");
        while(true){
          System.out.print(String.format("Ingrese el nombre del d% producto: ",i));
          String producto=entry.nextLine();
          System.out.print("Ingrese el precio del producto: ");
          double precio=entry.nextDouble();
          String descuento;
          if(precio>500){
            descuento="20 %";
            precio*=0.80;
          }
          else{
            descuento="5 %";
            precio*=0.95;
          }
          regist(producto,String.valueOf(Math.round(precio*100.0)/100.0),descuento);
          System.out.print("Desea agregar otra compra[SI/NO]: ");
          String de=entry.nextLine().toUpperCase();
          if(de.equals("NO")){
            break;
          }
          i++;
          System.out.println();
        }
        mostrar();
    
      }
    
      public static void regist(String producto,String precio,String descuento){
        registro.add(producto);
        registro.add(precio);
        registro.add(descuento);
      }
    
      public static void mostrar(){
        int x=0;
        for(int i=0;i<registro.size();i++){
          x++;
          if(x%3==0){
            System.out.println(registro.get(i));
            System.out.println();
          }
          else{
            System.out.print(registro.get(i));
          }
        }
      }
    
    
    }
```

**Error que me muestra Java**

> *Exception in thread "main" java.util..UnknownFormatConversionException:Conversion='p'
> at.java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2691)
> at.java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.(Formatter.java:2720)
> at.java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
> at.java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
> at.java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
> at.java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
> at.Ejercicio8.main.(Ejercicio8.java:13) java.exited with code:1*

Comment: "_Ingrese el nombre del **%d** producto_", no _"d%"_.  Por eso te dice que no reconoce el formato de conversión y te lanza un error..

Comment: gracias si me funciono. Pero ahora en la parte de las entradas de datos principalmente en:"String de=entry.nextLine().toUpperCase();" .Aqui pasa que no me reconoce este metodo para poder ingresar datos y si lo cambion ya no con "nextLIne" sino con "next" ahi si me aparece para poder ingresar pero sucede que lo de arriba al momento de ingresar el nombre del producto y el precio, ambos se ajuntan y no me permiten ingresar el primero que es el nombre del producto.

Comment: Prueba cambiando entry.nextDouble(); por Double. parseDouble(entry.nextLine());. Por cierto lo ideal, para que lo hagas al estilo java, sería que crearas una clase Producto.